# Vuetify при подключение ломается

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, vuetify

Только подключил vuetify к проекту и он выбивает такую ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если надо вот [Git проекта](https://github.com/Papa2Carlro/admin-panel)

Раньше на проекте использовался materialize. Подключен в файле index.html, так как в npm 1.0.2 версии не было, и бустрап (Верстал на бутрапе, а ui компоненты брал из materialize)

Думал проблема в конфликте с бутстрапом, отключаю, ничего не меняется

```
/// /src/admin/plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

```
/// /src/main.js

import Vue from "vue";
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'
import Paginate from 'vuejs-paginate'
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import vuetify from "@/admin/plugins/vuetify"
import messagePlugin from '@/admin/utils/message.plugin'
import "./registerServiceWorker";

Vue.use(Vuelidate)
Vue.use(messagePlugin)

// Component
Vue.component('Paginate', Paginate)

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  vuetify,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том что надо использовать sass а не node-sass